# Environment variables for the current user with Python

Tags: python, environment-variables, env

How can you get a list of the environment variables for the current user ("user variables") using Python?

`os.environ()` returns the system variables, and changing those requires admin access.

I want to have it change the user variables for PATH, as that can be done without any restrictions.

Comment: You want to change the PATH var only for your program or you want to modify the user's PATH forever?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What I need is to add a folder to path, and there are 2 options (2 PATH variables): one in "system variables" that requires admin rights to change, and one in "user variables" that doesn't

Comment: For windows I can recommend a module to set variables through registry. Also has CLI app: https://github.com/beliaev-maksim/py_setenv this has good control on user/system level and does not have limit in length as setx

Answer (score 3):

That's wrong. `os.environ` returns the environment of current process. At this level, there is no notion of user or system variables.

You can of course change any of these environment variables. For `PATH` just do :

```
os.environ['PATH'] = new_path
```

But you are only changing the **current process** environment. That means that this new environment will be used by current process and all its childs, but will vanish at the end of the process.

**There is no portable way to modify the environment of the calling shell**

Anyway in windows, you can modify the permanent environment variables with the command `setx`. For example if you want to set on change the user environment variable `FOO` to `bar`, you could do in a python script :

```
import os
os.system("setx FOO bar")
```

But this change will only be used by processes started from Windows explorer after the command has been executed. In particular neither the environment of the python script nor the one of the calling `cmd.exe` if any will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

```
import subprocess
raw_path = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command","[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User')"], capture_output=True) 
user_path = raw_path.stdout.decode('ascii').split(';') print(user_path)
```